# Set the default value of a column: the value of another column

Tags: sqlite, default-value

Say I have a table where there are 2 columns of the same type and with the same constraints - they are 2 foreign keys.

Now I needed to set the default value of column2 to be equal to the current value of column1. Is that possible upon the creation of the table and without the use of triggers for insertion/update - I mean without doing it manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A column's default value must be constant:

```
> CREATE TABLE t(x, y DEFAULT (x));
Error: default value of column [y] is not constant
```

Such a default value would require a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER default_y_from_x
AFTER INSERT ON t
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.y IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE t SET y = NEW.x WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```